# AVCodecContext::channel_layout 0 for WAV files

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, wav, codec

I have been successfully loading compressed audio files using FFmpeg and querying their channel_layouts using some code I've written:

```
AVFormatContext* fmtCxt = nullptr;
avformat_open_input( &fmtCxt, "###/440_sine.wav", nullptr, nullptr );
avformat_find_stream_info( fmtCxt, nullptr );
av_find_best_stream( fmtCxt, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, nullptr, 0 );

AVCodecContext* codecCxt = fmtCxt->streams[ret]->codec;
AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder( codecCxt->codec_id );
avcodec_open2( codecCxt, codec, nullptr );

std::cout << "Channel Layout: " << codecCxt->channel_layout << std::endl;
av_dump_format( fmtCxt, 0, "###/440_sine.wav", 0 );
```

I've removed all error checking for brevity.  However for Microsoft WAV files (mono or stereo) the `AVCodecContext::channel_layout` member is always 0 - despite `ffprobe` and `av_dump_format(..)` both returning valid information:

```
Input #0, wav, from '###/440_sine.wav':
Duration: 00:00:00.01, bitrate: 740 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

Also `codecCxt->channels` returns the correct value.  Using a flac file (with *exactly* the same audio data generated from the same application), gives a `channel_layout` of 0x4 (`AV_CH_FRONT_CENTER`).

Comment: I should state I'm using FFmpeg 2.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your WAV file uses FFmpeg's pcm_s16le codec, which have no information on channel layout. You can only have the number of channels. A lot of explanations can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463006.aspx)

You have the correct `channel_layout` with the flac file because FFmpeg's flac codec fills this field. You can find the correspondence table on [libavcodec/flac.c](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/flac.c;hb=HEAD) file, the `flac_channel_layouts` array.

If you need to fill `channel_layout` manually, you can call:

`codecCxt->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout( codecCxt->channels );`